# Bash script and Reverse ssh tunneling

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to write a `bash` script to allow me to connect my device which may behind `firewall` or `NAT` (Somehow impossible to connect directly). Under some circumstances, my script should establish reverse ssh connection to myserver (which has public ip) and make a get request to some endpoint to send tunneled port number and device mac.

I use the command below to establish ssh connection

```
ssh -R "*:0:localhost:22" -N -T mypi@myserver
```

This command connects the `myserver`'s port `22` (ssh-server will listening to) and opens a tunnel to random port. The port number printed to `stdout`

```
Allocated port 33238 for remote forward to localhost:22
```

What I want is simply make a GET request to server and send this `port` number with device `macId`. When there are more than one device, it is hard to find without knowing which device tunneled to which port on server, and I want to solve this. I couldn't make static the port since there are many device may wants to connect same time.

However, the command I am using for ssh tunneling is blocking the output so when I try to read `stdout` with the following code, it never breaks the while loop, as expected.

```
myssh-command |
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    echo "$line"
  done
```

If I use ssh's `-f` flag to put command in background, I couldn't read `stdout`.

To sum, I stuck and I am newbie in `bash` scripting. Is there a way to execute reverse ssh tunneling in background and get the port number from stdout at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to place the ssh process in the background using

```
ssh ..... > fileWithPortNumber &
```

And then read the file to figure out the port number.
Is that kinda what you are looking for? If so search the Internet for **bash job control** for more information.